Ansible playbook and docker_compose task failing after updates
Would anyone be kind enough to help me?
I'm continuing to have issues with this after an update. I'm running an ansible playbook with each service defined as a role and individual tasks bringing up the containers.
Experiencing error this error: 'container.image_config['ContainerConfig'].get('Volumes') or {}'
and it is recreating my containers with hashed names e.g. 419bbc4d6207_grafana
I have the below task in defined under my role.
- name: Run docker compose for Grafana
  docker_compose:

Here is a full traceback.
  File "/tmp/ansible_docker_compose_payload_on1b18vl/ansible_docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py", line 865, in cmd_up
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 697, in up
    results, errors = parallel.parallel_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
    result = func(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 679, in do
    return service.execute_convergence_plan(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 579, in execute_convergence_plan
    return self._execute_convergence_recreate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 499, in _execute_convergence_recreate
    containers, errors = parallel_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
    raise error_to_reraise
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
    result = func(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 494, in recreate
    return self.recreate_container(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 612, in recreate_container
    new_container = self.create_container(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 330, in create_container
    container_options = self._get_container_create_options(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 921, in _get_container_create_options
    container_options, override_options = self._build_container_volume_options(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 960, in _build_container_volume_options
    binds, affinity = merge_volume_bindings(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 1548, in merge_volume_bindings
    old_volumes, old_mounts = get_container_data_volumes(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 1579, in get_container_data_volumes
    container.image_config['ContainerConfig'].get('Volumes') or {}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "errors": [],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_version": "auto",
            "build": false,
            "ca_path": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "debug": false,
            "definition": null,
            "dependencies": true,
            "docker_host": "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
            "env_file": null,
            "files": null,
            "hostname_check": false,
            "nocache": false,
            "profiles": null,
            "project_name": null,
            "project_src": "/home/x/github/ans_play/roles/grafana/",
            "pull": false,
            "recreate": "smart",
            "remove_images": null,
            "remove_orphans": false,
            "remove_volumes": false,
            "restarted": false,
            "scale": null,
            "services": null,
            "ssl_version": null,
            "state": "present",
            "stopped": false,
            "timeout": null,
            "tls": false,
            "tls_hostname": null,
            "use_ssh_client": false,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "module_stderr": "Recreating 419bbc4d6207_grafana ... \n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "Error starting project 'ContainerConfig'"
}

